# Provide geolocation data to iOS from Windows

Tags: ios, windows, geolocation, gps

I'd like to use a computer using Windows 7 to provide data to an iOS device. I guess there is no way to do that by Wifi so I'd like to simulate a bluetooth GPS device on my Windows 7 computer so that the iOS device would connect to it.

My question is, what kind of data should I sent ? Can I directly send NMEA frames or should I implement another Apple protocol ? Where can I find specification on those protocol in iOS ?

The idea is to make geolocation data to be available to the whole system. Maybe by "simulating" a bluetooth external GPS receiver using a software that I would develop on Windows. So what kind of data should my Windows software send by bluetooth to iOS ? And how can it be detected by iOS as an external GPS receiver ?

Thanks.

Comment: If you only want the data to be accessible in your iOS app, then you can use any network protocol (HTTP, whatever). If you want the geolocation data to be available to the whole system, then I'm afraid that it's impossible without custom/specialized hardware.

Comment: The idea is indeed to make geolocation data to be available to the whole system. This is why I'd like to "simulate" a bluetooth external GPS receiver using a software that I would develop on Windows.

Comment: I believe this might not be possible. You would need a special bluetooth hardware, that would allow you to manipulate/send/receive bluetooth data (frames) at a very low-level. This is not accessible from standard devices and from standard programming tools. You would need special drivers for this, and Windows is probably a bad platform for such experiments.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use [bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29).
It's a auto-connecting protocol which finds other "player" in the same subnet (lets say same "WiFi".

Theres a [windows sdk](https://developer.apple.com/opensource/) written in C:
https://developer.apple.com/opensource/

How you do submit the data is up to you. You might create a JSON payload out of your GPS Data. You can also create a binary format and compress it with libz (zip) before sending it to your iOS Device through bonjour.

Comment: The idea is to make geolocation data to be available to the whole system. This is why I'd like to "simulate" a bluetooth external GPS receiver using a software that I would develop on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set up a web server and a web service on your PC and simple connect to it through local network (WiFi) from your device. I think this requires the least work from both server and client side. Which format do you use (JSON, fractions of NMEA, something else) is really up to you since you will have to code both server and client side. For JSON and XML however there are a lot of free frameworks and even some SDK support on both client (iOS) and server (php, asp, servlets, etc) side.

Comment: The idea is to make geolocation data to be available to the whole system. This is why I'd like to "simulate" a bluetooth external GPS receiver using a software that I would develop on Windows.

Comment: And which framework would you use on iOS to receive this data?

Comment: the native iOS Location Services

Comment: And how will you make it use your data instead of that one of the onboard gps?

Comment: It seems to be automatic. When I connect my external GPS to the iPad, it automatically uses it.